# PETScVector could not be imported

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to use MPI in OpenMDAO. I get the following error. It seems to come from [this](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/core/problem.py). But I don't understand what is causing this error or how to fix it.

```Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/RBMDO/Power_Subsystem.py", line 494, in <module>
    prob.setup()
  File "/home/users/.conda/envs/my-fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 874, in setup
    raise ValueError(self.msginfo +
ValueError: Problem: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but PETScVector could not be imported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/RBMDO/Power_Subsystem.py", line 494, in <module>
    prob.setup()
  File "/home/users/.conda/envs/my-fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 874, in setup
    raise ValueError(self.msginfo +
ValueError: Problem: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but PETScVector could not be imported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/RBMDO/Power_Subsystem.py", line 494, in <module>
    prob.setup()
  File "/home/users/.conda/envs/my-fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 874, in setup
    raise ValueError(self.msginfo +
ValueError: Problem: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but PETScVector could not be imported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/rpandi/RBMDO/Power_Subsystem.py", line 494, in <module>
    prob.setup()
  File "/home/users/.conda/envs/my-fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 874, in setup
    raise ValueError(self.msginfo +
ValueError: Problem: Attempting to run in parallel under MPI but PETScVector could not be imported.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:
```

I verified MPI and petsc are working in my environment, I ran the small petsc4py script given [here](https://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/getting-started/mpi_linux.html). It runs successfully and gives the expected result.

For completeness, I am running a MINLP optimization with AMIEGO and my job script is below.

```Shell
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH -C skylake

print_error_and_exit() { echo "***ERROR*** $*"; exit 1; }
module purge || print_error_and_exit "No 'module' command"
module load lang/Anaconda3/2020.02
module load mpi/OpenMPI/3.1.4-GCC-8.3.0

conda activate my-fastenv

mpirun -n $SLURM_NTASKS python /RBMDO/Power_Subsystem.py
```

Any idea on what might be causing this error ?

Comment: this looks like a problem with your install. You should submit a bug report https://github.com/openmdao/openmdao/issues and the developers may be able to give some more insight there.

Comment: Thank you. Link to the corresponding bug report : [link](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/2128)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error recently while running an airfoil shape optimization problem, using ADflow within OpenMDAO framework. I am posting what worked for me after going through the 'link of the bug report' as posted by skyrider in the comment section. I am currently using PETSc 3.18.5. All the versions after PETSc 3.14 install the petsc4yp version automatically while installing the corresponding PETSc version. This automatic installation of petsc4py wrapper caused the Import Error. To resolve the import error, I downloaded pets4py-3.18.5.tar.gz directly (from [here](https://petsc.org/release/install/download/)). Then unzip it using `cd petsc4py-3.18.5` and install it using `pip install .` This re-installed petsc4py wrapper and the import error was resolved completely.

Cheers!